# Disable PopUp when using CTRL+C on a TextBox used for password

Tags: vb.net, winforms, textbox

I am using a `TextBox` for Password input.  When I do a <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> on any contents I get a PopUp:

> **Not Allowed
> You cannot copy text from a password field**

Is there any way to disable this message?  I have my own error reporting and don't need the message.

```
Imports System.ComponentModel      
Imports cTimeDisplay

Public Class PwdTextBox
    Inherits TextBox

    Private p_MaskCharacter As Char = "●"c
    <Browsable(False)>
    Public Property MaskCharacter As Char
        Get
            Return p_MaskCharacter
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Char)
            p_MaskCharacter = value
            Me.PasswordChar = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private p_ErrorDisplay As Label
    <Browsable(False)>
    Public Property ErrorDisplay As Label
        Get
            Return p_ErrorDisplay
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Label)
            p_ErrorDisplay = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Protected Overrides Sub OnKeyUp(e As KeyEventArgs)
        Const SCP As Keys = Keys.Shift Or Keys.Control Or Keys.P
        Const CA As Keys = Keys.Control Or Keys.A
        Const CP As Keys = Keys.Control Or Keys.P
        Const CC As Keys = Keys.Control Or Keys.C
        If (e.KeyData = SCP) Then
            If (Me.PasswordChar = p_MaskCharacter) Then
                Me.PasswordChar = Nothing
            Else
                Me.PasswordChar = p_MaskCharacter
            End If
        End If

        If (e.KeyData = CA OrElse e.KeyData = CP OrElse e.KeyData = CC) Then
            TimeDisplay.Display(p_ErrorDisplay, "No Copy/Paste For PWD-CTRL Disabled")
        End If

        MyBase.OnKeyUp(e)
    End Sub
End Class
```

I added the code described below but I may be doing something wrong as this doesn't work

```
Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As Message)
    Dim EM_SHOWBALLOONTIP = &H1503

    If (m.Msg = EM_SHOWBALLOONTIP) Then
        m.Result = IntPtr.Zero
    End If

    MyBase.WndProc(m)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Mat.  I always have trouble posting here.

Comment: Override WndProc in a custom control derived from TextBox and set `m.Result = IntPtr.Zero` when you receive a [EM_SHOWBALLOONTIP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/em-showballoontip) ( `= &H1503`) message.

Comment: Thanks Jimi.  I went nuts on the internet trying to find an answer.

Comment: Call `base.WndProc(...)` only if you didn't process the message. E.g., `if m.Msg = EM_SHOWBALLOONTIP then m.Result = IntPtr.Zero
else mybase.WndProc(m) end if`. Move the declaration of `EM_SHOWBALLOONTIP` outside the method, to a const int field (not important, but better).

Comment: Thanks once again.  That worked.